# Implementing a function to delete a specific record in Muddatagrid

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui, mudblazor

how can I implement a function to delete a specific record in a data grid in mudblazor? I implemented the datagrid and tried hard to get the id of the record which I need to delete. How can I do it by using a function?

```
<MudItem xs="12" Class="pt-0">
   <div id="unique_id_scroll_section" class="ma-0" style="height:200px;overflow: auto">
   <MudDataGrid Items="@Elements" Hover="true" Striped="true" Dense="true">
          <Columns>
                <Column T="Menuitemlist" StickyLeft="true">
                     <CellTemplate>
                          <MudIconButton OnClick="@(() => PrcdBtnClick())" Color="@Color.Default" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Delete" />
                     </CellTemplate>
                </Column>
                <Column T="Menuitemlist" Field="ItemName" Title="Name" />
                <Column T="Menuitemlist" Title="Qty" Style="width:10px" />
                <Column T="Menuitemlist" Field="OptionalSalesPrice" Title="Price" Style="width:10px" />
                <Column T="Menuitemlist" Title="Total" Style="width:10px" /></Columns>
            </MudDataGrid>
   </div> 
</MudItem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the item from Elements and trigger rerender. You are approaching it from the wrong end, otherwise it's fairly simple.

Here you have a working example how to delete a row from MudDataGrid:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wkmRYGwOoxVtLoaC

Main.razor:

```
@using Models

<MudItem xs="12" Class="pt-0">
   <div id="unique_id_scroll_section" class="ma-0" style="height:200px;overflow: auto">
   <MudDataGrid Items="@Elements" Hover="true" Striped="true" Dense="true">
          <Columns>
                <Column T="Element" StickyLeft="true">
                     <CellTemplate>
                          <MudIconButton OnClick="@(() => PrcdBtnClick(@context.Item))" Color="@Color.Default" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Delete" />
                     </CellTemplate>
                </Column>
                <Column T="Element" Field="Name" />
                
            </Columns>
    </MudDataGrid>
   </div> 
</MudItem>

@code { 

    private IEnumerable<Element> Elements = new List<Element>(){new Element("Uranium"), new Element("Radium"), new Element("Cobalt")};

    private void PrcdBtnClick(Element x)
    {
        Elements = Elements.Where(u => u.Name != x.Name);
    }

}
```

Element.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Models
{
    public class Element
    {
        public string Group { get; set; } = "Group";
        public int Position { get; set; } = 1;
        public string Name { get; set; } = "Plutonium";
        public int Number { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("small")]
        public string Sign { get; set; } = "Piesces";
        public double Molar { get; set; } = 6.9;
        public IList<int> Electrons { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Sign} - {Name}";
        }

        public Element(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

You need to use @context.Item to retrieve item of Elements associated with current row.

Comment: @Danul Hivi Edit added.

Comment: Thank you for your help mate. That worked. Can you give me a solution to reduce the column size of that data grid?

Comment: That's fine. Just ask another question with the tag "Blazor" and I will see what I can do. That way there will be some order. You can link this thread.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75518646/16241720 please answer this question.

Comment: There is an issue. If I add same item twice to the order and when I try to delete the item it will delete all the items in the list. I need to select the row id. how can I do that?

Comment: You cannot select a row id. What you would have to do is to generate an id when the the table is rendered and assign it to an object. Then you can select from the list (enumerable) the item by its id. This begs for a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75660546/16241720 can You answer this question?

Comment: Can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76296422/16241720