# Reducing column width of datagrid of blazor hybrid app

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, hybrid-mobile-app

How can I reduce the column width of the Muddatagrid? I tried hard but couldn't able to find a way.

```
<MudItem xs="12" Class="pt-0">
     <div id="unique_id_scroll_section" class="ma-0" style="height:200px;overflow: auto">
           <MudDataGrid Items="@Elements" Hover="true" Striped="true" Dense="true">
                 <Columns>
                       <Column T="Menuitemlist" StickyLeft="true">
                            <CellTemplate>
                                  <MudIconButton OnClick="@(() => RemoveItem(@context.Item))" Color="@Color.Default" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Delete" />
                            </CellTemplate>
                       </Column>
                       <Column T="Menuitemlist" Field="ItemName" Title="Name" />
                       <Column T="Menuitemlist" Title="Qty" Style="width:10px" />
                       <Column T="Menuitemlist" Field="OptionalSalesPrice" Title="Price" Style="width:10px" />
                       <Column T="Menuitemlist" Title="Total" Style="width:10px" />
                  </Columns>
            </MudDataGrid>
       </div> 
</MudItem>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you want is <ColGroup>

My working example:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GEQduGQloFYGtWvh

```
@using Models

<MudItem xs="12" Class="pt-0">
   <div id="unique_id_scroll_section" class="ma-0" style="height:200px;overflow: auto">
   <MudDataGrid Items="@Elements" Hover="true" Striped="true" Dense="true">
        <ColGroup>
            <col style="width: 60px;" />
            <col />
        </ColGroup>
          <Columns>
                <Column T="Element" StickyLeft="true">
                     <CellTemplate>
                          <MudIconButton OnClick="@(() => PrcdBtnClick(@context.Item))" Color="@Color.Default" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Delete" />
                     </CellTemplate>
                </Column>
                <Column T="Element" Field="Name" Style="20px !important;" />
                
            </Columns>
    </MudDataGrid>
   </div> 
</MudItem>

@code { 

    private IEnumerable<Element> Elements = new List<Element>(){new Element("Uranium"), new Element("Radium"), new Element("Cobalt")};

    private void PrcdBtnClick(Element x)
    {
        Elements = Elements.Where(u => u.Name != x.Name);
    }

}
```

The reference in docs is burried here:
https://mudblazor.com/components/table#grouping-(basic)---initially-collapsed

Comment: Your answer is working https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GEQduGQloFYGtWvh on this platform. but still isn't working with my project. what would be the reason for that? I searched for an answer. But still the issue is same.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/wnv94R please find this link. That includes the whole code part.

Comment: I also added this mudnumberfield component but it isn't showing also. I added that code part to the code in the above link. please give solutions for these 2.

Comment: I tried my example with MudBlazor 6.1.0 and .Net 6 and it works just fine. Which versions are you using? Can you provide minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I'm using mudblazor 6.1.8 and .net 7. The dotnet version is different from yours. Can you give me a solution for that version? Minimal reproducible example means?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please use this link. https://codeshare.io/0gvQbN

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75578782/16241720 can you solve this?