# How can I fit the app to full screen of the blazor app

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, hybrid-mobile-app

when I try to use full-screen mode it doesn't open and there is the lower part under the content. How can I set it to full screen in blazor hybrid app? How can I fix that? I tried many ways, but didn't work. I'm using .net 7.

```
<MudLayout Style="height:contain">

<MudGrid Style="width:100%;height:100%">
<MudItem xs="12" Class="d-flex align-center justify-center" >
    <MudGrid>
        <MudItem xs="2"></MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="8">
            <MudGrid>
                <MudItem xs="12" Class="d-flex align-center justify-center pl-16 pr-16 mr-16 ml-16">
                    <MudGrid>
                        <MudItem xs="3"></MudItem>
                        <MudItem xs="6">
                            <MudTextField @bind-Value="loginModel.UserName" Required="true" Label="User Name" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Margin="Margin.Dense"></MudTextField>
                        </MudItem>
                        <MudItem xs="3"></MudItem>
                    </MudGrid>

                </MudItem>
                <MudItem xs="12" Class="d-flex align-center justify-center pl-16 pr-16 mr-16 ml-16 ">
                    <MudGrid>
                        <MudItem xs="3"></MudItem>
                        <MudItem xs="6">
                            <MudTextField @bind-Value="loginModel.Password" Label="Password" Required="true" Variant="Variant.Outlined"
                                          InputType="@PasswordInput" Adornment="Adornment.End" AdornmentIcon="@PasswordInputIcon"
                                          OnAdornmentClick="ButtonTestclick" AdornmentAriaLabel="Show Password" Margin="Margin.Dense" />
                        </MudItem>
                        <MudItem xs="3"></MudItem>
                    </MudGrid>

                </MudItem>
                <MudItem xs="12" Class="d-flex align-center justify-center pl-16 pr-16 mr-16 ml-16  ">
                    <MudGrid>
                        <MudItem xs="3"></MudItem>
                        <MudItem xs="6">
                            <MudTextField @bind-Value="Environmentname" Label="Environment Name" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Margin="Margin.Dense"></MudTextField>
                        </MudItem>
                        <MudItem xs="3"></MudItem>
                    </MudGrid>

                </MudItem>
                <MudItem xs="12" Class="d-flex align-center justify-center pl-4 pr-4 mr-16 ml-16 ">
                    <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" OnClick="LgnBtnClick" Style="background-color:#02198B;color:white;width:120px;height:45px;font-size:larger;border-radius:10px">
                        Login
                    </MudButton>
                </MudItem>
                
            </MudGrid>
        </MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="2"></MudItem>
    </MudGrid>
</MudItem>
 </MudGrid>
 </MudLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @maciek can you?

Comment: Do you mean full screen as in no toolbar or do you just want to space the components out vertically?

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the xml for one screen inside the webview but you want your app to open fullscreen. But the webview is wrapped in an UWP app, you need to make the UPW app fullscreen. go to the maui app builder and add an and event like this:

```
var builder = MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();


builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
{
    events.AddWindows(wndLifeCycleBuilder =>
    {
        wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
        {
            var hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
            var myWndId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);
            var _appWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(myWndId);
            _appWindow.SetPresenter(AppWindowPresenterKind.FullScreen);
        });
    });
});
```

This code adds an event to the maui app for windows only. That on startup gets the window the app is running in and makes that window full screen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75660546/16241720 can You answer this question?

Comment: @DanulHiviVihan I see you found your solution on the other question, if this anwser solved you question, mark is as so. so when other people find this it might help them

Comment: where I can do that? can you do that for me. I can't find that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75672361/16241720 this is a different question. can you suggest a solution for this

Comment: Can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76296422/16241720