# Overflow issue in react js web application

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, overflow

This is the styles sheet I'm using. There is an overflow issue when using this in mobile and tablet views but there isn't any issue in desktop view. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?I'm developing a reactjs webapp and hosted in firebase.
If I add less number of tech languages it won't show any error. But when I add more it will give overflow issue. Then it will be a horizontally scrollable.

```
const AboutPageStyles = styled.div`
  padding: 20rem 0 10rem 0;
  .top-section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 2rem;
  }
  .left {
    flex: 3;
  }
  .right {
    flex: 2;
  }
  .about__subheading {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    span {
      background-color: var(--deep-dark);
      padding: 0%.5rem;
      border: 8px;
    }
  }
  .about__heading {
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
  }

  .about__info {
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    .para {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  }
  .button {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    background-color: ${(props) =>
      props.outline ? 'transparent' : 'var(--gray-1)'};
    padding: 0.3em 1em;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid var(--gray-1);
    color: ${(props) => (props.outline ? 'var(--gray-1)' : 'black ')};
  }

  .right {
    img {
      border: 1px solid var(--gray-1);
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
  }
  .about__info__items {
    margin-top: 15rem;
  }

  .about__info__item {
    margin-bottom: 10rem;
  }
  .about__info__heading {
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    padding: 10rem 0;
    .top-section {
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 5rem;
    }
    .about__subheading {
      font-size: 1.8rem;
    }

    .about__heading {
      font-size: 2.8rem;
    }
    .about__info__heading {
      font-size: 3rem;
    }
    .button {
      font-size: 1.8rem;
    }
  }
`;

<div className="about__info__item">
          <h1 className="about__info__heading">My Skills</h1>
          <AboutInfoItem
            title="FrontEnd"
            items={[
              'HTML',
              'CSS',
              'JavaScript',
              'C#',
              'ReactJS',
              'Blazor',
              'MAUI',
              'XAML',
            ]}
          />
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the full component? As a live preview?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/QnDkRx please look this

Comment: It's not clear. Can you try to provide a working example? Try using https://codesandbox.io/s/ and select React as the template.

Answer (score -1):

please add **box-sizing:border-box;**

Comment: Where I can add this box-sizing?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).